# Test Custom Headers ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can you test custom headers in ActionMailer?  For example, if you have specified the "errors-to" header, how would you access it in your test?

```
    email.headers['errors-to']  # returns nil
    email.headers               # returns {}
```

The [testing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers) doesn't reference any custom headers.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out!

```
email.header['errors-to']
```